# Can not debug with attach to process VS Pro 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, w3wp, attach-to-process, w3wp.exe

I deployed my MVC project to IIS and now I need to debug code by attach process but it not work.
These are steps that I did to debug:

> 1. Run my solution with Visual Studio Pro 2017 as Admin
> 2. Debug -> Attach to process...
> 3. Attach w3wp.exe process
> 4. Restart my site in IIS Manager
> 5. Run my site in browsers to debug

After above steps, my breakpoints always warning:

> The breakpoint will not current be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

I can debug my code in the other PC with above steps but this way have problem with my laptop.
How can I fix this?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by:

> 1. Debug -> Options...
> 2. Uncheck at **"Enable Just My Code"**

I installed the newest Visual Studio Professional 2017 (15.8.5) to my laptop. In this version, above option is checked as default.